# Generics for two classes: .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, generics, .net-6.0

I am trying to instantiate class with common fields using generics.

```
if (payload?.tableA?.name == "a")
{
    Report rpt = new Report ();
    ABC a = rpt.FillReport<ABC>(payload);
}
else
{
     Report rpt = new Report();
     BCD b = rpt.FillReport<BCD>(payload);
}
```

Now the field for `ABC` and `BCD` are as follows

```
class A{
   pageId, paperType, printType, Volume
}

class B{
  pageId, paperType, paperColor, Volume, Weight
}
```

So now How should  I use generics here.This is what I tried.

```
public T FillReport<T>(DTO? dto) where T : ABC, new()
{
    T report = new T();
    report.pageId = dto.pageId;
    report.paperType= dto.paperType;
...
}
//Works for only ABC, how Do it BCD fields.
```

Comment: where T: class, new()

Comment: Though the details are a little fuzzy (this is not a [mre], in particular the details of `DTO` are unclear) I'm going to guess that this is probably a job for Automapper, as the alternative is some odious manual reflection or type switching.

Comment: You're calling FillReport on an instance of report, but then creating a new Report within that method. Is that correct? Sorry to detract from the question. Just seems weird to have 2 instances of that when I'd expect everything to just use the original instance. But without context it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface `ISomething` and make ABC/BCD both inherit from that same interface:

```
public interface ISomething 
{
    pageId {get;set;}
    pagerType {get;set;}
}

class A : ISomething
class B : ISomething
```

Then on your method declaration:

```
public T FillReport<T>(DTO? dto) where T : ISomething, new()
```